# How do I increase reputation with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

The Stack Overflow user guidelines tell me I must have a reputation of at least 50 before I can comment (answer a question). It also strongly suggests, via the wording, that I can't ask questions before earning a reputation of 50.

Although this is allowing me to ask my question without any reputation at all. So, what is asking a well thought out, prior researched question worth in reputation score?

Comment: Help Center: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Also, read the short introductory [tour].

Comment: Apparently not this way because you just lost reputation. smh

Answer (score 11):

It looks like we haven't clearly explained the difference between comments and questions. You can ask questions as soon as you sign up. Comments are made in response to a question. They are often used to ask clarifying information about a question. Once you've been on the site a little bit and have been actively asking/answering questions, you'll gain the reputation points needed to be able to post comments.

Comment: I would agree that your guidelines were not clear enough to begin with.  Especially since I, on my system, have never had opportunity to scroll ALL THE WAY down to the bottom, where I can answer a question.  (Good answers to the complex questions I had were already answered long before any "opportunity" for that.)  As a new user of Stack Overflow, and obvious neophyte to asking questions here, I was expecting that there would have been two buttons, side by side, "Comment" and an "Answer" jump link to clearly distinguish between the two; if there was a difference.  Thanks.  I stand informed.